# If controller jexl3 is not evaluating the condition correctly

Tags: if-statement, groovy, jmeter, controller, jsr223

My script uses a while loop and an if controller as a child for evaluating a condition using jexl3 and determining if a particular request should or not run; this is how my test plans look like:

[While Controller Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLYxy.png)

The "While Controller2" value should equal 5 to set the while controller condition to true and exit the test

[If Controller Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofByX.png)

The "If Controller" evaluates if a determinate if a request should run or not, depending on the current "${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}_skip" value; note that _skip is append to the variable.

[Request Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXK2s.png)

There are the requests that run depending on the if condition evaluation; as you can see, the "${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}" is sent, and the path field and "counter" variable is also appended at the end.

[Counter Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOyN6.png)

And the counter is incrementing 1++ with its maximum value as "${MultitrackerId_matchNr}"

[Debug Sampler with variables values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YMC4.png)

This is a Debug Sampler to show you the values of the variables before the thread enters, for example, the main "While Controller2". The "MultitrackerId" has 4 possible values, and the counter starts in "1"

according to the test plan requirements, the MultitrackerId values are sent sequentially because of the counter, and each value should stop being sent when the response body contains "SUCCESSFUL", and the same thread should continue sending the request as many times as required to all the remaining "MultitrackerId values" contains "SUCCESSFUL" in their responses.

NOTE: depending on the length of the received data, each "MultitrackerId" value could require "n" iterations to get the "SUCCESSFUL" string present on its response

For handling the previous requirements, I am using a JSR223 Postprocessor as a child of the main above-shown request. A "matches" variable is defined starting from 0. It's incremented if the previous response contains "SUCCESSFUL", in addition, for avoiding to repeat a request that has already received the "SUCCESSFUL" string in its response, I am defining a new variable called "variable", using the current MultitrackerId value with a "_skip" value appended and finally, the same variable is set to true.

```
def matches = vars.getObject('matches') ?: 0

if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("SUCCESSFUL")) {

    vars.putObject('matches', matches + 1)
    def variable = '${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}'
    vars.put(variable + '_skip', "true")

}
```

When I run the test, the request is evaluated in the "if" condition, and if the "SUCCESSFUL" is contained in the response, matches increase +1 to update the main "While" condition and send the next MultitrackerId value.

I am expecting each MultitracketId already evaluated in the JSR223( SUCCESSFUL and marked with _skip) to be skipped in the "If Controller" condition; this is an example of the final "Debug Sampler"

[Final Debug Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyMDf.png)

Despite the matches variable being equal to "5" and the test stopping because of the "While Controller" condition, the requests evaluated in the JSR223 "if" as response with "SUCCESSFUL" and marked with "_skip" are being sent again, so the "matches" variable is reaching its expected value "5", others MultitrackersId values could be still pending to receive "SUCCESSFUL", so the test is finishing without being completed according with the requirements.

Let's remember the "If Controller" condition:

```
${__jexl3("${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}_skip" != "true",)}
```

When trying to debug the "If Controller" with the jexl3 condition, I am noticing that even if the MultitrackerId was evaluated in the JSR223 and set to "_skip", it's being evaluated once and once again

```
2023-01-06 21:44:57,423 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting script=def matches = vars.getObject('matches') ?: 0

if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("SUCCESSFUL")) {

    vars.putObject('matches', matches + 1)
    def variable = 's5KZoGfPawRt1RHkwechR'
    vars.put(variable + '_skip', "true")

}
```

```
2023-01-06 21:44:57,435 DEBUG o.a.j.c.IfController:     getCondition() : [true]

2023-01-06 21:44:57,436 DEBUG o.a.j.c.IfController:     >> evaluate Condition -  [true] results is  [true]
```

I would really appreaciate any idea for solving this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your script I can see:

1. In first While Controller you're using `<` operator to compare 2 [string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) values

   [image]

   I believe it needs to be changed to something like `${__jexl3(${matches} < 5,)}`
2. This bit: `def variable = '${__V(MultitrackerId_${counter})}'`

   According to [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

   > The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
   >
   > - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
   > - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
   >
   > When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

   I think you need to change it to `def variable = vars.get('MultitrackerId_' + vars.get('counter'))`

   or just move function to Parameters section and refer it as `Parameters`

   [image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)